# Concatenate in theano scan

Tags: theano

I am having trouble figuring out why the following code doesn't work:

```
import theano as th
import theano.tensor as tt

a = tt.vector("a")

res, up = th.scan(
    fn = lambda a : tt.concatenate([a,a]), 
    outputs_info = a,
    n_steps = 2
)

f = th.function(inputs = [a], outputs=res)

f(np.array([1.]))
```

I would expect it to return the same as if

```
f = th.function(
    inputs = [a], 
    outputs = tt.concatenate([tt.concatenate([a,a]),tt.concatenate([a,a])])
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `theano.scan` docstring:

> ... the initial state **should have the same shape** as the output ...

If your scan involves a recurrent expression on a vector, then the shape of that vector must not change.

```
lambda a: T.sqr(a)  # OK

lambda a: T.concat([a,a])  # ERROR
```

The reason for that, scan internally uses a matrix to store your vector on all time steps. If the shape changes, the matrix would be ragged. While theoretically not impossible to implement, it introduces a lot more complexity and potential issues.

So, yeah, `scan` is a bit limited.